# remove all submenus from plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin

Is there a way to un register all submenus at once instead of using the code below?

```
remove_submenu_page('myplugin', 'sub-page-1'); 
remove_submenu_page('myplugin', 'sub-page-2'); 
remove_submenu_page('myplugin', 'sub-page-3'); 
remove_submenu_page('myplugin', 'sub-page-4'); 
remove_submenu_page('myplugin', 'sub-page-5');
...
...
```

The idea is...

```
remove_submenu_page('myplugin', all);???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without touching the global `$submenu` directly (which I wouldn't recommend - using only purposefully exposed APIs provides, in general, better stability).

However, if you wanted a function to remove all submenus:

```
/**
 * Removes all submenus of given menu item
 *
 * @param string $menu_slug The slug of the parent menu to remove submenus of
 */
function wpse137406_remove_submenus( $menu_slug ) {
    global $submenu;

    if ( isset( $submenu[$menu_slug] ) ){
         unset( $submenu[$menu_slug] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay well ill skip the use of the global and stick to some extra lines of code....thanks!